# Data seperated by multiple spaces, want to put them in a .txt file line by line

Tags: python, regex

I have data in a weird format, where I have three numbers inside of brackets, separated by about 13 spaces. They are all on the same line. It looks like this:

```
(4.99951e-05 0 0)             (2.40627e-06 7.19079e-09 -2.97063e-10)             (2.4056e-06 -7.22339e-09 -2.93301e-10)             (4.99951e-05 0 0)             (2.4056e-06 -7.22341e-09 7.33252e-11)             (4.99951e-05 0 0)             (4.99951e-05 0 0)             (2.40627e-06 7.19082e-09 7.42658e-11) 
... etc
```

I want to save them in a new txt file, with each vector on its own line like:

```
(4.99951e-05 0 0)
(2.40627e-06 7.19079e-09 -2.97063e-10) 
(2.4056e-06 -7.22339e-09 -2.93301e-10)
...
```

I am not entirely sure how to go about this. usually I read files line by line with python but I am not sure how to read numbers when they're all on the same line

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use, assuming your line of data is `line`

```
import re
results = re.split('  +', line)
#   splits on two or more spaces
```

which returns a list:

```
[
(4.99951e-05 0 0),
(2.40627e-06 7.19079e-09 -2.97063e-10),
(2.4056e-06 -7.22339e-09 -2.93301e-10),
(4.99951e-05 0 0),
(2.4056e-06 -7.22341e-09 7.33252e-11),
(4.99951e-05 0 0),
(4.99951e-05 0 0),
(2.40627e-06 7.19082e-09 7.42658e-11)
]
```

which you can then process as you see fit.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html for full coverage of `re` module and all the things you can do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something quick, might not be the best way, but have a look, you could get a better way after looking at this.

```
s = "(4.99951e-05 0 0)             (2.40627e-06 7.19079e-09 -2.97063e-10)             (2.4056e-06 -7.22339e-09 -2.93301e-10)             (4.99951e-05 0 0)             (2.4056e-06 -7.22341e-09 7.33252e-11)             (4.99951e-05 0 0)             (4.99951e-05 0 0)             (2.40627e-06 7.19082e-09 7.42658e-11)"

result = ""
is_parenthesis = False
for char in s:
    if not is_parenthesis or char == ")":
        result += char
    if char == ")":
        is_parenthesis = True
        result += "\n"
    elif char == "(":
        is_parenthesis = False
        result += "("
print(result)
```